# Getting rid of the Sign function

Tags: simplifying-expressions

I am trying to fully simplify the following function using `FullSimplfy` but I am still getting it with the `Sign` function. Is there any way to have a simplified one without the `Sign` function?

```
expr = 0.00441039 (Sqrt[2 π] Abs[-6 + t]^3 + Sqrt[2 π] Abs[t]^3 + 18.7497 (-1. + t)^3 Sign[1. - 1. t] + 130.745 (-1.5 + 1. t)^3 Sign[1.5 - 1. t] - 896.268 (-2. + t)^3 Sign[2. - 1. t] + 2198.61 (-2.5 + 1. t)^3 Sign[2.5 - 1. t] - 2898.66 (-3. + t)^3 Sign[3. - 1. t] + 2198.61 (-3.5 + 1. t)^3 Sign[3.5 - 1. t] - 896.268 (-4. + t)^3 Sign[4. - 1. t] + 130.745 (-4.5 + 1. t)^3 Sign[4.5 - 1. t] + 18.7497 (-5. + t)^3 Sign[5. - 1. t])
```

I used the following command:

```
FullSimplify[expr]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a piecewise function.

```
f = 0.00441039 (Sqrt[2 \[Pi]] Abs[-6 + t]^3 + 
 Sqrt[2 \[Pi]] Abs[t]^3 + 18.7497 (-1. + t)^3 Sign[1. - 1. t] + 
 130.745 (-1.5 + 1. t)^3 Sign[1.5 - 1. t] - 
 896.268 (-2. + t)^3 Sign[2. - 1. t] + 
 2198.61 (-2.5 + 1. t)^3 Sign[2.5 - 1. t] - 
 2898.66 (-3. + t)^3 Sign[3. - 1. t] + 
 2198.61 (-3.5 + 1. t)^3 Sign[3.5 - 1. t] - 
 896.268 (-4. + t)^3 Sign[4. - 1. t] + 
 130.745 (-4.5 + 1. t)^3 Sign[4.5 - 1. t] + 
 18.7497 (-5. + t)^3 Sign[5. - 1. t]);

PiecewiseExpand[f, Reals] // Simplify
```

[image]

**Edit:  Appendix to your second question: Other form than Piecewise**

For real t, you can apply

```
f2 = f /. Sign[u_] -> u/Sqrt[u^2] /. Abs[u_] -> Sqrt[u^2] // Simplify
```

[image]

But the cases where u==0 are no more defined. There you have to take limit, e.g. `Limit[f2,t->1.5]` instead of  `f2/.t->1.5` .

If you want to avoid, that some points are not defined, rationalize the function and apply

```
f3 = Rationalize[f, 0];

f3 /. Sign[u_] -> u/Sqrt[u^2] /. Abs[u_] -> Sqrt[u^2] // FullSimplify

(*   (1/1000000000000)441039 (-(653725/4) ((3 - 2 t)^2)^(3/2) - 
      5496525/2 ((5 - 2 t)^2)^(3/2) - 5496525/2 ((7 - 2 t)^2)^(3/2) - 
      653725/4 ((9 - 2 t)^2)^(3/2) + 
      10000 Sqrt[2 \[Pi]] ((-6 + t)^2)^(3/2) - 
      187497 ((-5 + t)^2)^(3/2) + 8962680 ((-4 + t)^2)^(3/2) + 
      28986600 ((-3 + t)^2)^(3/2) + 8962680 ((-2 + t)^2)^(3/2) - 
      187497 ((-1 + t)^2)^(3/2) + 10000 Sqrt[2 \[Pi]] (t^2)^(3/2))   *)
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Is there any way to write it in the same form of the original function and just without the `Sign` function? I mean not as the piecewise  form. I need to write it in Latex for a nicer view.